# Node.js: how many bits in a String?

Tags: javascript, string, node.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How many bytes in a JavaScript string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219526/how-many-bytes-in-a-javascript-string)
>   [String length in bytes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515869/string-length-in-bytes-in-javascript)

How can I calculate how many bits in a String?
Actually what I need is how many octets (8-bit bytes) in a JavaScript(V8) String?
If it's impossible to know, is there any other characters data structure that can be helpful here instead of String?

UPDATE: for UTF-8 encoding

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i would like to send it back to a browser as an http response body, I need to know the content length, I don't want to use the 'http' module.

Comment: Depends on the charset and the encoding. If it's ASCII, transferred as ASCII, then one byte per char. If it's Unicode transferred as UTF-8 then... you will need to do some computations!

Comment: can I know what is the charset and the encoding of a specific String?(NodeJS)

Comment: I don't know about node.js, but in principle a JS string has no encoding per se (well, actually it's handled as UTF-16 internally, but that's probably irrelevant). You need to _choose_ an encoding when serializing the string as a stream of octets. And you need to _tell the browser_ about the encoding you have chosen, typically with an appropriate HTTP header.

Comment: I see, so when I write a String to a socket, the default is UTF-8, how can I calculate the number of octets for this encoding?

Comment: There's a very short and nice solution for NodeJS. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46321139/1852787

Answer (score 3):

<s>Assuming you are only using BMP characters</s>:

```
/* Compute length of UTF-8 serialization of string s. */
function utf8Length(s)
{
    var l = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        var c = s.charCodeAt(i);
        if (c <= 0x007f) l += 1;
        else if (c <= 0x07ff) l += 2;
        else if (c >= 0xd800 && c <= 0xdfff)  l += 2;  // surrogates
        else l += 3;
    }
    return l;
}
```

If you get out of BMP (i.e. use characters above 0xffff) things get more complicated, as they will be seen in JavaScript as surrogate pairs that you will have to identify...

**Update**: I updated the code so that it works with all of Unicode,
not only BMP.
However, this code now relies on a strong assumption: that the given
string is *correct* UTF-16. It works by counting two bytes for every
surrogate found in the string. The truth is that a surrogate *pair*
is encoded as 4 bytes in UTF-8, and no surrogate should ever be found
outside a pair.

Comment: Can you explain what is '0x007f'?what does it represent?

Comment: 0x007f is 127 in hex: it's the upper limit of ASCII and the highest Unicode codepoint encoded as a single byte in UTF-8. 0x07ff is the highest codepoint encoded as two bytes. See [Wikipedia:UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf8).