# How many bytes are required to store one character in .NET and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, .net

How many bytes are required to store one character in:

- Microsoft's implementation of the .NET framework, version 4
- JavaScript, as implemented by Microsoft Internet Explorer 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both [.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx#Characters) and [JavaScript](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-4.3.16) use [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16). UTF-16 is a so-called *variable-length* encoding which uses 16-bit *code units* to represent Unicode *code points* (which are 21 bits in length). Historically it came from [UCS-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UCS-2) when Unicode was still a 16-bit code (which was deemed insufficient later, thus the expansion to 21 bits).

Since UTF-16 uses 16-bit code units the code *itself* is a 16-bit code, but to represent a *character*, you'll have to look a bit closer to what you actually mean:

1. *Character* in the Unicode sense means *Unicode code point* which is probably your intended meaning. Here are two cases:

   1. A code point in the range  U+0000 to  U+FFFF takes up two bytes, because it can be represented in a single UTF-16 code unit (here code unit and code point are identical).
   2. A code point in the range U+10000 to U+10FFFF takes up four bytes because it has to be represented using *two* UTF-16 code units.
2. Character in the usual meaning often refers to *graphemes*, actually, which would be what we perceive as a single character. Those can have arbitrarily many diacritics, or may be ligatures that are formed out of multiple code points by the rendering engine. Long story short in this case: Those can be arbitrarily long since they can consist of several code points.

Answer (score 1):

.net and JavaScript  both are UTF-16:

> Represents each Unicode code point as a sequence of one or two 16-bit
>   integers. Most common Unicode characters require only one UTF-16 code
>   point, although Unicode supplementary characters (U+10000 and greater)
>   require two UTF-16 surrogate code points. Both little-endian and
>   big-endian byte orders are supported.

So it can be 16bit or 32 bit.

- [Char .net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.aspx)
- [How many bytes in a JavaScript string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219526/how-many-bytes-in-a-javascript-string)

Comment: Neither is 16-bit. Both use UTF-16 (with some peculiarities around JavaScript), which is a variable-length encoding, the name notwithstanding.

Comment: UTF-16 means that it uses 16-bit *code units* to represent the 21-bit *code points* of Unicode. So you need one or two such code units for a single code point, depending on the code point.