# Limit html text input to a particular number of bytes?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, forms

Using HTML5 (or less preferably JavaScript) is it possible to limit the maximum length of an `input` to a particular number of bytes?

I realise that I can limit to a number of characters with:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="4" />
```

But that's not good enough because I can input up to four two-byte chars in it.

Obviously I am validating this server-side, but I would like this on the browser-side too.

**Edit:** Just to be clear, I do wish to be able to support UTF-8. Sorry @elclanrs.

Comment: clientside+serverside ajax?

Comment: Or maybe just limit the characters on `keydown` with something like `/[\w\s]+/` which will be all 1byte.

Comment: The user can input up to four characters, each of which can be up to four bytes long when UTF-8 is used. I don’t see the point of this question. Why would you limit input to a certain amount of bytes? The data will be processed as *characters* anyway.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Thank you for reminding me that non-ASCII chars can be more than 4 bytes. The data *will not be processed as characters* on the server. It is an unavoidable limitation that I must use a particular number of bytes.

Comment: @AlessandroGabrielli I'm not really enamoured with that solution, as I wish to keep traffic to a minimum, but it may come to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this script has a couple minor UX glitches that can be cleaned up, but it does accomplish the basic task outlined when i tested it in chrome:

```
<input id=myinp />


<script> // bind handlers to input:
   myinp.onkeypress=myinp.onblur=myinp.onpaste= function vld(e){
     var inp=e.target;
     // count bytes used in text:
     if( encodeURIComponent(inp.value).replace(/%[A-F\d]{2,6}/g, 'U').length > 4){
        // if too many bytes, try to reject:
        e.preventDefault;
        inp.value=inp.val||inp.value;
        return false;
     }
     // backup last known good value:
    inp.val=inp.value;
   }

</script>
```

Comment: This looks great, thank you! According to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290182/how-many-bytes-takes-one-unicode-character UTF-8 may have up to 6 bytes for any character. A colleague explained to me that this will work only with one and two-byte chars. Do you see a way of making it work with more?

Comment: 2 bytes fits all major web-used languages AFAIK (i'd love a contra if somone has one). i modified my answer to support 6-char escape codes, but i think 4 chars should be enough for anyone, but i'm no linguist....

Comment: This is prone to under-count. For the text: 'I am a 19 char text', this method counts 17 bytes, which is incorrect. You could use `encodeURIComponent(inp.value.replace(/\d/g,'X')).replace(/%[A-F\d]{2,6}/g, 'U')` instead.

Comment: To count bytes, this may be useful :  `new Blob([str]).size` .. found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52254083/2628312)

Answer (score 1):

Throughout my own findings, I figured this works really well:

```js
function limit_input(n) { // n = number of bytes
  return function(e) {
    const is_clipboard = e instanceof ClipboardEvent;
    if(is_clipboard && e.type != "paste") {
      return;
    }
    let new_val = e.target.value;
    if(is_clipboard) {
      new_val += e.clipboardData.getData("text");
    } else {
      new_val += e.key;
    }
    if(new TextEncoder().encode(new_val).byteLength -
       e.target.selectionEnd + e.target.selectionStart > n) {
      if(e.target.value == "" && is_clipboard) {
        const old = e.target.placeholder;
        e.target.placeholder = "Text too long to paste!";
        setTimeout(function() {
          e.target.placeholder = old;
        }, 1000);
      }
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  };
}

let el = document.getElementById("your_input");

el.onkeypress = el.onpaste = limit_input(4);
```

I started out with dandavis' answer and kept on improving it to adapt to all situations. I still don't think this is perfect, and it's still using the deprecated `onkeypress` handler, but nothing else worked better than this.

You can delete the part of the code that changes `placeholder` to say the text is too long to paste (delete the whole `if`, keep only `e.preventDefault()` in). It's just something I added myself to notify the user why the input is still empty after they try pasting something in. That way they won't blame me for writing faulty code and I won't have to answer a horde of complaints.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function that returns the byte length of a string, then validate the input according to your requirements.

Here's an example that returns the byte length of a string:

```
function getStringByteLength(str) {
  str = typeof(str) === 'string' ? str : '';
  const byteSize = new Blob([str]).size;
  return byteSize;
}
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r1fn0yo6/) that has a working example of calling the function above to validate two different text inputs.

Answer (score 0):

If estimating isn't good enough, I'd filter all the non single-byte chars and count them.