# Calculate size of the text in a text area

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am just trying to implement Secured Upload functionality. Instead of asking user to select a file to upload, I have a textarea where user can paste the contents. I will parse it in JS.

I want to limit based on size not based on number of character. If it is number of charatcters, then I can easily implement it in JS

**Doubts**

1) Is it safe to limit data based on size?

2) I am new to JS. In C, One char is one byte. So I can calculate size easily. In JS, How can I do that?

3) If JS is also same as C style sizing, then does it browser dependent?

Any suggestions?

I am not interested in `max length` property of `text area`.

**SIZE**

I mean size by kilo bytes, mega bytes,..

Comment: Please see the edits Mr Lister.

Comment: Well, in C one char is one byte, i think it's a bit more like one char is one octet no ?
And tell me why, in a different language, size of types would change ?

Comment: Ah, I see. If your question is that you want to know how many bytes the size of a string is in JavaScript, this is a duplicate of [How many bytes in a JavaScript string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219526/how-many-bytes-in-a-javascript-string)

Comment: @AxelLavielle in JavaScript, 16 bits!

Comment: @MrLister It depends of the charset you're using ^^

Comment: @MrLister I am interested in other doubts as well. So It cannot be duuplicate

Answer (score 0):

This should produce approximately the same number although file upload is including file details and text upload only contains the file contents.

```
<script>
function test() {
    console.log(document.getElementById('file' ).files[0 ].size);
    console.log(document.getElementById('text').value.length);
}
</script>
<input id="file" type="file" />
<br/>
<input type="text" id="text" />
<br/>
<button onclick="test();">test</button>
```