# Can I use charCodeAt() when I use utf-8?

Tags: javascript, utf-8

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt

I need to calculate byte size by given string which given from `<input />`.

I've found javascript function `charCodeAt()` which seems to be good to use.

It says charCodeAt uses utf-16, but I use `<meta charset="utf-8"/>`

Is it okay to use `charCodeAt()` in utf-8?

Comment: Although an HTML document might be encoded with UTF-8, HTML, semantically, doesn't have anything to do with any character encoding, only the Unicode character set. Any, you are right, JavaScript uses the UTF-16 character encoding. So, what is your question about byte count and UTF-8? Please show your code it applicable.

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked about `charCodeAt()` but FYI looks like you can use:

```
new Blob(['string']).size
```

Or if using Node:

```
Buffer.byteLength('string', 'utf8')
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52254083/5670890