# Why does toString('hex') result in twice the bytes in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, binary, hex, byte

I feel like I'm missing something very basic, but not sure.

```
crypto = require('crypto')

bytes = crypto.randomBytes(32)

str = bytes.toString('hex')

Buffer.byteLength(str) //64 why....?
```

Ok found it

1 hex = 4 bits (2^4 = 16) also (0,1,2,3...D, E, F = 16)

2 hex = 8 bits

1 byte = 8 bits (definition of byte)

1 byte = 2^8 = 256 possible values (0-255)

1 hex = 16 possible values (0-F)

2 hex = 16^2 = 256 possible values (00-FF)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a hex-**string** from the raw-bytes - as far as I know characters of a string are stored in 16bit and since 16 bits equal 2 bytes (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219526/how-many-bytes-in-a-javascript-string) for more information), you get a total length of `64` for the resulting string. The length of the `bytes`-array will still be `32`.