# How to calculate the actual byte size of an Array in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, buffer, sizeof, aws-elasticsearch

I'm doing a bulk indexing in AWS OpenSearch within my node application and it's failing because the chunk size are too big. Below is the error

```
Request size exceeded 104857600 bytes
```

So I need to calculate the actual chunk size in bytes. So I tried with below 2 ways and not sure which one is correct.

```
// with Buffer
const str = 'tree'
const obj = [{a:'sas'},{a:'e'}]
console.log(Buffer.from(str).length); ---> 4
console.log(Buffer.from(obj).length); ---> 2

// with object-sizeof
var sizeof = require('object-sizeof')
const str = 'tree'
const obj = [{a:'sas'},{a:'e'}]
console.log(sizeof(str)); ---> 8
console.log(sizeof(obj)); ---> 12
```

It seems 'Buffer' takes 1 Byte for a char while 'object-sizeof' takes 2 bytes for a char. So what is correct here? And which is the correct way to check the byte size of actual object array?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

For *any type* of value:

```
const { serialize } = require('v8')

// i.e
const variable = true 

console.log(serialize(variable).byteLength) // 3
```

3 = `0x03 0x01 0x00`

Header byte indicating the type of the value (which is 0x03 for a boolean), followed by a byte indicating the value of the boolean (which is 0x01 for true and 0x00 for false)

---

Using: `Buffer.byteLength(string, 'utf8')`, would force one to use `Buffer.byteLength(string.toString(), 'utf8')`, which would be 4 for `true` and 5 for `false`, and for objects, would always be 15 due to `[Object, Object]`, one could also do `Buffer.byteLength(JSON.stringify(object), 'utf8')`, which would also return the incorrect value of used memory.

Answer (score 0):

According to answers on [How many bytes in a JavaScript string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219526/how-many-bytes-in-a-javascript-string) you can use `Buffer.byteLength(string, 'utf8')` to get the byte size of a string.

Anyway, the size of a char in javascript is 2 bytes, so i guess it's the same with typescript/node.js : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString/Binary