# JavaScript heap out of memory issue on comparing elements in large for loops

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have huge JSON file to process which holds around 15,00,000 JSON objects. I am performing some searching operation where I am using two for loops under which I am comparing object values.

Below is an example:

```
const data = [
 {
  "slug": "vertical-lift-module-market",
  "id": 68055,
  "related_reports_updated": {
  "sub_categories": [
    {
      "slug": "audience-analytics-market",
      "id": 66684,
      "short_title": "Audience Analytics Market"
    },
    {
      "slug": "mobile-wallet-market",
      "id": 68830,
      "short_title": "Mobile Wallet Market"
    }
  }
},
{
"slug": "united-states-real-estate-services---growth-trends-and-forecast-2022-- -2027",
"id": 68056,
"related_reports_updated": {
  "sub_categories": [
    {
      "slug": "canada-real-estate-services-market---growth-trends-and-forecast-2020---2025",
      "id": 68051,
      "short_title": "Canada Real Estate Services Market"
    },
    {
      "slug": "germany-real-estate-services-market--growth-trends-and-forecast-2020---2025",
      "id": 68054,
      "short_title": "Germany Real Estate Services Market"
    },
  }
 },
 {
  ...
 }  
]
//This data holds 15,00,000 JSON objects
```

What I am trying to do is comparing `slug` of one object with `slug` available in `sub_categories` array of other objects. If it's present then create one object and push it into the `result` array and send that `result` array.

```
const result = [];

for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
  
   for(var j=0;j<data.length;j++) {

        //Comparing operation
  }

} 

console.log(result);
```

But after running some time, it's giving me this error:

```
[41955:0x523ce90]   162238 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 4096.9 (4102.7) -> 4096.9 (4104.7) 
MB, 3481.7 / 0.4 ms  (average mu = 0.092, current mu = 0.000) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
1: 0xa3ac10 node::Abort() [node]
2: 0x970199 node::FatalError(char const*, char const*) [node]
3: 0xbba58e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) 
[node]
4: 0xbba907 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char 
const*, bool) [node]
5: 0xd76b25  [node]
6: 0xd776af  [node]
7: 0xd854eb v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, 
v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
8: 0xd890ac v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, 
v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, 
v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
9: 0xd5778b v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, 
v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [node]
10: 0x109fd4f v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, 
v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
11: 0x1448f59  [node]

Aborted (core dumped)
```

To get rid of this error I even tried `node --max-old-space-size=4096 index.js` for maximizing memory for node processes.

But I am still getting the same issue. Is there any other way to resolve this issue and get the desired result?

Comment: Are you trying to extract the `names` from the objects in array by excluding duplicated `names` ?

Comment: `result` will always have all names from `data` because both loops iterate over all elements in `data`. That's a really wasteful way to get a copy of `data` + a bunch of empty objects... -> What are you trying to accomplish with that script ([XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/))?

Comment: I have updated my post with actual problem statement.

Comment: Iterate over the elements and add all sub-slugs into a `Set` and in a second run check the slugs against that `Set`. Exit the inner loop as soon as you've found a match (there's no need to iterate over the whole array). Try to split the work into smaller chunks. Use worker threads. ...

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that any element have word and number.

- double precision 64-bit number in js takes 8 bytes*
- word with 5 letters is around 10 bytes**

If single element have 18 bytes then

```
1.5e6 elements is 2.7e7 bytes = 27 MB
```

Independently from code:

```
         const obj = {};
             
         if(data[i].name == data[j].name) {
              obj.name = data[i].name;
         }
```

you pushing to `result` array in double loop. Any of these loops goes through `1.5e6` elements so summary you are going to add to `result` a lot elements, in this case: `1.5e6` * `1.5e6` = `2.25e12`.

Now let's compute size of `result`

`2.25e12` * (`8 bytes` + `10 bytes`) = `4.05e13 bytes`

We know that
1 gigabyte = 1 000 000 000 bytes = 1e9 bytes
1 terabyte = 1e12 bytes

So in your case you need 40 terabytes to save your `result`.

Definitely you have to rethink algorithm that you want to implement.

---

*each number actually takes up an average of 9.7 bytes. [source](https://www.mattzeunert.com/2016/07/24/javascript-array-object-sizes.html)

**we can assume 2 bytes per character for but it can be 5 or more bytes [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219526/how-many-bytes-in-a-javascript-string)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a less complex algorithm that does not add duplicate values, it will push much lower number of elements into result array.

```
let dictionary = {};

// O(n) to build dictionary of all parent slugs
for(let i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   dictionary[data[i].slug]=1; // hashing
}

// O(n*k) to check dictionary instead of doing O(n*n*k) for brute-force
for(let i=0;i<n;i++)
for(let j=0;j<data[i].sub_cat.length;j++)
{
    // O(1)
    if(data[i].sub_cat[j].slug in dictionary)
        dictionary[data[i].sub_cat[j].slug]++; // 2 => will go to result
}


// add to result O(n)
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(dictionary)) {
  if(value==2)
      result.push(key);
}
```

Since it also compares to itself, like element 5 vs element 5, it may still duplicate as in comparison but not as result item. So you may need to add an extra comparison for that depending on required algorithm.