# What is the size in bytes of the string return from ObjectId.toString()

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, objectid, mongodb-indexes

```
const myObjectId = ObjectId("507c7f79bcf86cd7994f6c0e")
const myObjectIdString = myObjectId.toString()
```

`myObjectId` has a size of 12 bytes. But what about the size of `myObjectIdString`?

Comment: Surely writing `console.log(Buffer.from(myObjectIdString).length)` is way quicker than posting a Stackoverflow question. And as an additional bonus you get the answer instantly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many bytes in a JavaScript string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219526/how-many-bytes-in-a-javascript-string)

Answer (score 1):

This ObjectId  is a 24-character hexadecimal string representation and when it's represented as a string it's 24 bytes.